# Detect Document Height Change

Tags: javascript, domdocument

I'm trying to detect when my `document` height changes.  Once it does, I need to run a few functions to help organize my page layout.

I'm not looking for `window.onresize`.  I need the entire document, which is larger than the window.

How do I observe this change?

Comment: well, there isn't really an event for that, I guess you would have to use a timer function..

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that kind of recursion.  Plus, it get's jumpy.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532453/how-to-detect-document-size-change-in-jquery

Comment: I did and it didn't work for me.  It doesn't seem to be catching my `$.animate()`s, but it does pick when elements are removed/added.

Comment: Related - [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492683/104380)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

### Update (Oct 2020):

[resizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver/observe) is a wonderful API ([support table](https://caniuse.com/resizeobserver))

```js
// create an Observer instance
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => 
  console.log('Body height changed:', entries[0].target.clientHeight)
)

// start observing a DOM node
resizeObserver.observe(document.body)

// click anywhere to rnadomize height
window.addEventListener('click', () =>
  document.body.style.height = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1) + 'px'
)
```

```html
click anywhere to change the height
```

---

### Old answer:

Although a "hack", this simple function continuously "listens" (through setTimeout) to changes in an element's height and fire a callback when a change was detected.

It's important to take into account an element's **height** might change regardless of any action taken by a user (*resize*, *click*, etc.) and so, since it is impossible to know what can cause a height change, all that can be done to absolutely guarantee 100% detection is to place an interval height checker :

```js
function onElementHeightChange(elm, callback) {
  var lastHeight = elm.clientHeight, newHeight;

  (function run() {
    newHeight = elm.clientHeight;
    if (lastHeight != newHeight)
      callback(newHeight)
    lastHeight = newHeight

    if (elm.onElementHeightChangeTimer)
      clearTimeout(elm.onElementHeightChangeTimer)

    elm.onElementHeightChangeTimer = setTimeout(run, 200)
  })()
}

// to clear the timer use:
// clearTimeout(document.body.onElementHeightChangeTimer);

// DEMO:
document.write("click anywhere to change the height")

onElementHeightChange(document.body, function(h) {
  console.log('Body height changed:', h)
})

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.style.height = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1) + 'px'
})
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tozeqi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I know I'm digging up an old post here, but the checkDocumentheight function would just run constantly, right?  It seems like that would slow down the browser checking the document's height over and over again.

Comment: @Cloudkiller - yes it runs constantly, and yes it hurts performance, but I know no better way.

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi - I see no reason why it wouldn't work. Please debug it and explain which piece of code doesn't work specifically. Also iPad is a device, not a browser. Which browser was at fault here?

Comment: How to use it inside iframe?

Comment: @VISHMAY - can you explain **exactly** what you want to happen?

Comment: @vsync, 
Actually,In a page i've iframe and I've managed to set iframe height = iframe's inner content's height on onload and resize event of outer page so that scroll is avoided,
Now a popup is displayed inside iframe's content on the control's hover (which is at bottom). so my iframe is having scroll now which i don't want on hovering that item

Comment: @VISHMAY - you should open a new question and put a demo code. also you must mention if both the iframe and the parent window are on the same domain or not.

Comment: The live demo outputs the document's width, not height on both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Please never ever use `setTimeout` to poll for changes.  On slower devices it will render your website unusable.  Many commercial websites now have this problem.  If there really is no event listener you can use, please give up on whatever minor enhancement you were trying to implement, and suggest your boss takes a computer science course.

Please also if you completely change your answer, post a new separate answer.

Comment: @Jake - The `setTimeout` mentioned in my original answer runs at `200ms` intervals, which is eternity in terms of computing. It will never ever harm performance not even the slightest, unless the solution is applied for many hundreds of DOM elements, which is highly unlikely.  There's only a single DOM *read* operation here.

Comment: For me it was necessary to add '{ }', see: `const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => { //... });`

Answer (score 30):

You can use an `absolute` positioned `iframe` with zero width inside the element you want to monitor for height changes, and listen to `resize` events on its `contentWindow`.  For example:

HTML

```
<body>
  Your content...
  <iframe class="height-change-listener" tabindex="-1"></iframe>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
.height-change-listener {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

JavaScript (using jQuery but could be adapted to pure JS)

```
$('.height-change-listener').each(function() {
  $(this.contentWindow).resize(function() {
    // Do something more useful
    console.log('doc height is ' + $(document).height());
  });
});
```

If for whatever reason you have `height:100%` set on `body` you'll need find (or add) another container element to implement this on.  If you want to add the `iframe` dynamically you'll probably need to use the `<iframe>.load` event to attach the `contentWindow.resize` listener.  If you want this to work in IE7 as well as browsers, you'll need to add the `*zoom:1` hack to the container element and also listen to the 'proprietary' `resize` event on the `<iframe>` element itself (which will duplicate `contentWindow.resize` in IE8-10).

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgn6jnmh/)...

Comment: I think this is quite a smart solution, however it would be better to use `100vh` instead of `100%` for the reasons you described. You would however lose compatibility with some older browser that do not support viewport-height.

Comment: @Tim - `100vh` would be the height of the viewport (aka window) whereas we want the height of the document (i.e. the content, which is not the same thing) to detect when that changes, which `100%` provides.  (It is easy to detect when the viewport height changes with the `window.resize` event.)

Comment: you're right, don't know why I thought that would be better.

Comment: This is really clever - thank you @Jake! And if you were to define a named function, the JS can even be a one-liner (if that's your style): `$($('.height-change-listener')[0].contentWindow).on('resize', doSomethingMoreUseful);`

Comment: If anyone wants this as an npm package: https://github.com/bertyhell/element-height-observer

Comment: When dynamically adding iframe, it seems it was working without attaching after `onLoad` is this expected? Here is a codesandbox and more details - https://stackoverflow.com/q/74295618/1828637

Comment: @Noitidart It depends on timing, and specific browser implementation.  It may work sometimes if you attach before the `load` event, but sometimes what you're attaching to may not have been fully initiallized.  To cover all bases and also attach as soon as possible, you can attach initially and then check on `load` if your event handler was actually attached.

Comment: @AnthonyM.  Thanks.  I adapted the invisble `iframe` idea from a solution to deal with missing `resize` and/or `orientationchange` events from early mobile browsers.  It can be adapted for any purpose where you want to know if some part of your displayed content has changed in size (vertically or horizontally).  I would never use a continuous polling loop, as it will cripple performance on slower machines.

Answer (score 14):

**Update: 2020**

There is now a way to accomplish this using the new [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver). This allows you to listen to a whole list of elements for when their element changes size. The basic usage is fairly simple:

```
const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    // each entry is an instance of ResizeObserverEntry
    console.log(entry.contentRect.height)
  }
})
observer.observe(document.querySelector('body'))
```

The one downside is that currently there is only support for Chrome/Firefox, but you can find some solid polyfills out there. Here's a codepen example I wrote up:

https://codepen.io/justin-schroeder/pen/poJjGJQ?editors=1111

Comment: It works, but not supported in Safari (of course IE not supported too)

Comment: Thats right > "The one downside is that currently there is only support for Chrome/Firefox, but you can find some solid polyfills out there."

Comment: As of Safari 13.1 released on Mar 24, it is supported.

Comment: All major browsers are supported now.

Answer (score 12):

Just my two cents. If by any chance you're using angular then this would do the job:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ 
 return document.height();
},function onHeightChange(newValue, oldValue){
 ...
});
```

Comment: You mean $(document).height(); ?

Comment: this doesn't work, it will only check the height on angular scope $digest, which doesn't cover many other ways the height can change, as css animations, images loading, and any js code that doesn't trigger angular digests (eg. non-angular libs)

Comment: The answer clearly states "If by any chance you're using angular". This being said - for angular based apps the above code did the job gracefully.

Comment: How does Angular detect the change?  Does it use an event listener of some sort or does it use wasteful and expensive polling that will cripple your site?  We need to know.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by vsync there is no event but you can use a timer or attach the handler somewhere else:

```
// get the height
var refreshDocHeight = function(){
    var h = $(document).height();
    $('#result').html("Document height: " + h);
};

// update the height every 200ms
window.setInterval(refreshDocHeight, 200);

// or attach the handler to all events which are able to change 
// the document height, for example
$('div').keyup(refreshDocHeight);
```

Find the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/54c9S/).

Comment: Please never ever use polling like this.  It will cripple your website on slower devices.

If there is no other way for the functionality you want to be implmented, please go back to your boss and say that it can't be done.

The web is now full of shoddy solutions like this, some on major websites, and almost becoming unusable.

Answer (score 1):

vsync's answer is completely fine. Just in case you don't like to use `setTimeout` and you can use `requestAnimationFrame` ([see support](http://caniuse.com/#search=requestAnimationFrame)) and of course you are still interested.

In the example below the body gets an extra event `sizechange`. And every time the height or width of the body changes it is triggered.

```
(function checkForBodySizeChange() {
    var last_body_size = {
        width: document.body.clientWidth,
        height: document.body.clientHeight
    };

    function checkBodySizeChange()
    {
        var width_changed = last_body_size.width !== document.body.clientWidth,
            height_changed = last_body_size.height !== document.body.clientHeight;


        if(width_changed || height_changed) {
            trigger(document.body, 'sizechange');
            last_body_size = {
                width: document.body.clientWidth,
                height: document.body.clientHeight
            };
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(checkBodySizeChange);
    }

    function trigger(element, event_name, event_detail)
    {
        var evt;

        if(document.dispatchEvent) {
            if(typeof CustomEvent === 'undefined') {
                var CustomEvent;

                CustomEvent = function(event, params) {
                    var evt;
                    params = params || {
                        bubbles: false,
                        cancelable: false,
                        detail: undefined
                    };
                    evt = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
                    evt.initCustomEvent(event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail);
                    return evt;
                };

                CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

                window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
            }

            evt = new CustomEvent(event_name, {"detail": event_detail});

            element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        else {
            evt = document.createEventObject();
            evt.eventType = event_name;
            evt.eventName = event_name;
            element.fireEvent('on' + event_name, evt);
        }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(checkBodySizeChange);
})();
```

[A live demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEGpyK)

The code can be reduced much if you have an own `triggerEvent` function in your project. Therefore just remove the complete function `trigger` and replace the line `trigger(document.body, 'sizechange');` with for example in jQuery `$(document.body).trigger('sizechange');`.

Comment: One disadvantage of using `requestAnimationFrame` as a replacement for `setTimout` (or perhaps `setInterval`) is that the size checking loop runs too often, every couple milliseconds. With `setTimeout` you can increase the loop interval to a reasonable amount.

Comment: @vsync's original answer is not fine - it is awful.  Please do not use polling unless you want to cripple your website.  If there are no events you can listen for then please give up on whatever feature you were trying to implement, for the benefit of everyone.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using @vsync's solution, like this. I'm using it for automatic scroll on a page like twitter.

```
const scrollInterval = (timeInterval, retry, cb) => {
    let tmpHeight = 0;
    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('interval');
        if (retry++ > 3) {
            clearInterval(this);
        }
        const change = document.body.clientHeight - tmpHeight;
        tmpHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        if (change > 0) {
            cb(change, (retry * timeInterval));
            scrollBy(0, 10000);
        }
        retry = 0;
    }, timeInterval);
    return myInterval;
};

const onBodyChange = (change, timeout) => {
    console.log(`document.body.clientHeight, changed: ${change}, after: ${timeout}`);
}

const createdInterval = scrollInterval(500, 3, onBodyChange);

// stop the scroller on some event
setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(createdInterval);
}, 10000);
```

You can also add a minimum change, and a lot of other things... But this is working for me

Comment: This is not an answer.  It is a comment.

Answer (score -2):

The command watch() checks any change in a property.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358072/how-to-detect-when-the-height-of-your-page-changes).

Comment: the WATCH command is not-standard and is only supported by GECKO..
http://goo.gl/11uqL BUT you can use a polyfill: https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

Comment: See the [big red warning here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)? **"Generally you should avoid using watch() and unwatch() when possible. These two methods are implemented only in Gecko, and they're intended primarily for debugging use. In addition, using watchpoints has a serious negative impact on performance"**