# How to handle document.body.clientHeight change in js?

Tags: javascript, events, document-body

I would like to listen to change on `document.body.clientHeight` it is possible and how?

For example when some node is appended into body, `clientHeight` is changed.

Comment: [Detect Document Height Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866775/detect-document-height-change)

Comment: And there, look at the *update 2020* answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `resize` event.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event